# Identify values of row on Datatables javascript PHP

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have problem to classify row from SQL which empty or not,
Here the sample of SQL data :

```
   ============================    
   |id | name      | notadp   |   
   ============================    
   |1  | johny     | e12sda3rd|    
   |2  | yes       |          |     
   |3  | papa      |          |   
   ============================
```

I want to classify using column `notadp` which is empty and will not show the button.

I tried with this code :

```
  {
      "data" : "notadp",
      "orderable": false,
      "className" : "text-left",
      "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
         globalData=row.notadp;
         if(globalData.length > 1){
         return '<i class="fa fa-file"></i>', 'class="btn btn-xs btn-success" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Nota Booking Fee"'
         } else {
         }
      }
  },
```

But the result for all rows shows the button. It should be just row 1. Is there any suggestion for my code above?

Thank you master

Answer (score 0):

there are a few issues with your code that are causing the button to be displayed for all rows. Here are the suggested changes to fix those issues:

Syntax Correction: In the return statement, you should enclose the button HTML within a single string. Currently, the button HTML is not properly enclosed.

Empty Check: You're checking if the length of globalData is greater than 1 to determine if the notadp column is empty or not. However, this condition will be true even if the column has a single character. To check if it's empty, you can use the if (globalData) condition instead.

### Here's the updated code with the suggested changes:

```js
{
  "data": "notadp",
  "orderable": false,
  "className": "text-left",
  "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
    globalData = row.notadp;
    if (globalData) {
      return '<button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Nota Booking Fee"><i class="fa fa-file"></i></button>';
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  }
}
```

---

With these changes, the button will only be displayed for rows where the notadp column is not empty. Rows with an empty notadp column will have an empty string as their output, and therefore, the button will not be rendered.

Comment: error still same bro, all rows show the button, actually only 1 row with value on column `notadp`